# Any example with loopback + passport + jwt?

Tags: session, passport.js, loopbackjs, json-web-token

Do you know any example code with loopback + passport + JWT?

The code in
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport and
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport
 seems to use sessions.

Or do yo know any alternative to passport with social login?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be of any help at all, but the [issue here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/issues/65) reveals a way of configuring loopback-component-passport to return a 'native' LoopBack access_token, rather than setting cookies, when you hit the `/auth/google/callback` endpoint.